# C# service drawing data from IB gateway interface. First daily bar fails

Tags: c#, service

I'm working with the IB Gateway API with a C# interface. When I request a daily bar I get the first daily update but after that I lose connectivity with that route. If I'm connected to 5 daily bar routes only first will fail and the rest will continue sending real time info. As a stop-gap measure I'm thinking of running one bar just to account for this. Has anyone else experienced this?

Thanks